# snakemake - using output file not explicitly declared as input for subsequent rule

Tags: ngs, nanopore, snakemake

I am writing a snakemake that, up to now should

1. use raw sequencing reads to produce a draft assembly using [canu](https://github.com/marbl/canu)
2. use [minimap2](https://github.com/lh3/minimap2) to align the raw reads against the draft assembly, generated by canu.

The following two rules are described below:

```
rule canu:
    input:
        fqdir + "{sample}.fastq"
    output:
        directory("{sample}/canu")
    shell:
        "/home/bhinckel/downloads/canu-1.9/Linux-amd64/bin/canu genomeSize=4.1m -p {wildcards.sample} -d {output} -nanopore-raw {input}"


rule minimap:
    input:
        reads = fqdir + "{sample}.fastq",
        draft_assembly = "{sample}/canu/{sample}.contigs.fasta"
    output:
        "{sample}/aligned/{sample}.sam"
    conda:
        "envs/general.yaml"
    shell:
        "minimap2 -ax map-ont {input.draft_assembly} {input.reads} > {output}"
```

However, if I do `snakemake -np` I get `Missing input files for rule minimap`. Which does make sense, after all I am not specifying the input for rule `minimap` (`{sample}/canu/{sample}.contigs.fasta`) anywhere i.e. snakemake cannot know that the file `{sample}/canu/{sample}.contigs.fasta` will be generated by canu.

The thing is that `canu` produces several files as output (amongst which the file `{sample}/canu/{sample}.contigs.fasta` is one of them), that's why I specified its output as a `directory`.

One way of solving this I guess would be to specify [all output files](https://canu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#outputs) produced by canu as an individual rule output (e.g. `{sample}/canu/{sample}.contigs.fasta`, `{sample}/canu/{sample}.report`, `{sample}/canu/{sample}.correctedReads.fasta.gz`), though I am looking for a more robust way to do so (if that's possible at all).

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to add one command after minimap: `touch done.txt`. This creates an empty file after minimap is finished. This can then be used in output rule for snakemake.

But specifying all the output files may not be a bad idea if these outputs are used in subsequent rules.